# Can the OS affect USB speeds?

Tags: linux, usb

Via a usb 2.0 port I am currently getting transfer speeds averaging at 17mb/s with bursts up to 26 mb/s, the ram and processor are barely being touched and this transfer speed affects all devices, using a small external SSD I only got an extra 1mb/s average.

Is there anyway my OS can affect the transfer rates this much? and if so what should I do to try and fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer at USB 2.0 speeds is no.

Overkill/detailed answer follows:

USB speeds
v1.0 (12 Mbs) - v2.0 (480 Mbps or 60 MBps) - v3.0 (5 gbps or 640MBps)

I work for a storage company, where for the past 2+ years, one of my tasks is high speed storage and maximizing transfer rates, both server to server and external drive to host OS. In particular, we focus on CentOS and Apple, though on Apple the interface is Thunderbolt.

OS issues come into play, when you talk about 10Gbps Ethernet of Fibre, such as on a Solarflare card or an ATTO fibre channel card, such as the ATTO Celerity FC-161E, which can do 16Gbps.

All that said, a few months ago, I had a very similar question. That is after working on this project for 2+ years. I had an external SSD and was trying to back up my 1TB disk at home. I was only backing up a portion of that and I did not fill up the disk by a long shot. I was connected via USB 3.0. Yes, I did use the blue 3.0 connector to my Windows 8.1 box, not the v2.0 black connector. I let the backup go for more than a day and it was still nowhere near done.

I then went to the electrical engineer here at work and complained about my slow performance and asked if Windows had anything to do with it. One would think that after preaching the response and tweaking cache settings on CentOS that I would know the response, but oh well.

Transfer speed is governed by the slowest component. All SSDs are NOT created equal and speed does vary. Vendors on external disk quote USB speeds, not the speed of the disk.

Also, what many people do not realize is that the number of writes to an SSD play a huge factor. SSDs can only have a certain number of writes per sector. All SSDs have "extra" space, but that overhead slows performance down as well, as the SSDs deal with that. This issue, however comes into play at higher speeds.

Many external disks either use slow flash memory, slow SSDs, or even worse a spinning disk. My WD Passport used a spinning disk, not a SSD. Although I did not use Black Magic or Iometer to test the speed, I did get very low speeds. That was just the nature of my disk.

eSATA, Thunderbolt (USB 3.1C), and Fibre channel are popular in industry precisely because they deliver high speed transfers.

The company where I work, came out with a high speed brick, which clocks data at 1.2 Gbps on average, but I have seen 1.3 and 1.4 Gbps off of the Apple Thunderbolt. That uses a very special kind of SSD and does many other things to achieve that speed. It is also, not a Thumbdrive or a WD passport size.

Tweaking the cache and USB settings on CentOS (in my case) do make a difference, but only at high speeds, not low ones.

You should research the actual internal specification on your drive. Do make note of random and sequential read and write speeds. Take into account the number of writes made on the drive, and the maximum number of writes permitted on the drive, if in fact SSD. WD passports used to use spinning disks, just made it look like a real SSD. Samsung makes different grade SSDs. We noticed that OCZ SSDs used to be the fastest, though the higher performance Samsung were not bad.

In order to give specifics, I would need to know the actual external storage that you used, as well as usage information.

I also do not know what kind of processor you have and how much memory. I use an Intel i7 box for testing with 32GB RAM and CentOS 7 64-bit for testing and tweaking. The Apple machine is a cylinder Mac Pro. You did not give the specification of your OS and machine. That can make a difference too if it is old or too small.

To know if you run into processor/memory issues, you can run system monitor and look at the overhead on the CPU and RAM, while doing transfers. If the CPU usage is low and RAM has a lot of free space during the transfer, then the problem is either your storage OR the destination drive, where you transfer to. If your local disk is busy, then it has to timeshare with the SSD.

You can use Black Magic disk speed test or Iometer to truly measure performance. You can also transfer data from the SSD to /dev/null, thereby eliminating the local disk and measuring read performance. You can also create a RAM disk with a file and then write from that to the SSD to gauge true write speeds. Try different computers.

The answer to your question involves research and eliminating variables.

Comment: Well here are a few key points (as a fellow R&D'er you can understand why I cannot disclose all technologies) but I am using a small board with 1GB of ram and an armvl7 (hard float) quad core. the external usb drive I am using is a 1TB samsung spin drive(m3 portable 1TB). I know you say do not make assumptions but while using this same drive (to back up my work) I got speeds of around 50mb/s (average). this is why I fear its limitations of the OS, I am going to try different OS'es on these boards. though so far I am at a dead end. this speed is hindering my project

Comment: @user1779617 Average sequential read/write speed for your drive is 85.2 MB/s with a minimum at 48.5 MB/s and a maximum of 111.3 MB/s as tested at http://www.cdrinfo.com/Sections/Reviews/Print.aspx?ArticleId=35453. Your drive is part # STSHX-M101TCB. Testing was done using several different software programs. Random access reduces performance, as does USB 2.0. Your sector size plays a factor too.BTW, I assume your 17mb/s is actually 17 MB/s (bytes per second). That is a bit low, but if random access and USB 2.0 and considering your low power drive that is not unrealistic.

Comment: @user1779617 When testing performance, always benchmark on a system that does not limit your performance, so that you know the starting point. In order to tweak the system, you have to know what the maximum you can expect. The previously mentioned article mentions several disk benchmark software tools: CrystalDiskMark, CrystlaDiskInfo, AS SSD, Iometer, ATTO Disk Benchmark, and HD Tune Pro. As mentioned in my answer Black Magic Disk Speed Test (on Apple) is not a bad tool either.